# Fetch action implemented in React Redux returns: "Cannot read property 'title' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

I want to implement an action which gets item by id, so I've created `fetchItemAction()`, as follows:

```
export const fetchItemAction = () => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: FETCH_ITEM_REQUEST,
  });
  return axios.get(`${url}/notes/5d4724cd62087b0e141f75a4`)
    .then(({ data }) => {
      console.log(data);
      dispatch({
        type: FETCH_ITEM_SUCCESS,
        data,
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      dispatch({
        type: FETCH_ITEM_FAILURE,
      });
    });
};
```

Then, I try to set `item` field in State in my reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  user: {},
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_ITEM_REQUEST:
        return {
            ...state,
            isLoading: true,
        };
        case FETCH_ITEM_SUCCESS:
        return {
            ...state,
            item: action.data,
            isLoading: false,
        };
    }
};
```

Then, I try to get those data in `Details` component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchItemAction } from 'actions/actions';

class Details extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { fetchItem } = this.props;
    fetchItem();
  }

  render() {
    const { item, isLoading } = this.props;
    return (
      <>
        {console.log(item)} 
        {/* <p>{item.title}</p> */}
      </>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ item, isLoading }) => ({ item, isLoading });

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  fetchItem: () => dispatch(fetchItemAction()),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Details);
```

As a result, I'm getting following data in console:
[image: Console]

Apart from two `undefinded` the result looks good because there is correct response from my backend.

But, when I try to uncomment `<p>item.title</p>` line in `Details.js`, the app crash:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
```

I also implemented correctly `fetchItemsAction()`, `addItemAction()` and `deleteItemAction()` which are very similar but I have no idea what is wrong in `fetchItemAction()`.

Comment: whats the value of `initialState` ?

Comment: I've updated the question: `isAuthenticated: false` and `user: {}`.

Comment: define `item` as `{}` in initial state. its failing because until you get the data, its value will be undefined.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mayank, initializing default item doesn't help me, but I've just received answer with explanation.

Comment: But, initialization in render: `const { item = {}, isLoading } = this.props;` helped. Thank you again Mayank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an asynchronous issue. `componentDidMount` is called when the component is mounted. Then, you're calling `fetch`. So on your first render, `item` is undefined. Once the data is returned, the render is triggered again with `item` data.

So, just check if `item` is defined:

```
render() {
  const { item, isLoading } = this.props;
  return (
    <>
      {console.log(item)} 
      {item && <p>{item.title}</p>}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: It works! Thank you very much for great explanation, I didn't know about this stuff and I didn't expect asynchronous issue here...

Comment: Another similar option is to use a function like Lodash.get() to safely get the value. On a prop like this, that isn't deeply nested, it wont make as much of a difference, but if you are trying to access a deeply nested value, using something like get can make your code easier to read and understand - plus it can be less code.